# Add If Else condition to an array

Tags: java, if-statement

I am having an isseue with the following program.

Here is the entire code and also I recently started to learn programming and this is my first project so I am not so good at indenting and the OOP concept. If one of you experts can turn this program into OOP that will be a great help to me.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;


class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String regNo;
    private int deposit;
    private int rate;

    public Car(String newMake, String newModel, String newRegNo,int newDeposit, int newRate) 
    {
            make = newMake;
            model = newModel;
            regNo = newRegNo;
            deposit = newDeposit;
            rate = newRate;
    }



    public String getMake() {
            return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
            return model;
    }

    public String getRegNo() {
            return regNo;
    }

    public int getDeposit() {
            return deposit;
    }

    public int getRate() {
            return rate;
    }
}

public class carrenta {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy  HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

List<Car> carlist = new ArrayList();
carlist.add(new Car("Toyota", "corolla", "TA7896", 1500, 1800));
carlist.add(new Car("Toyota", "vitz", "TV9872", 1500, 1800));
carlist.add(new Car("Nissan", "paso", "NP1543", 1500, 1500));
carlist.add(new Car("Honda", "city", "HC4692", 1800, 1800));
carlist.add(new Car("Honda", "civic", "HC4521", 2000, 1600));
carlist.add(new Car("Honda", " accord", "HA5463", 2500, 2000));
carlist.add(new Car("Mitsubishi", "lancer", "ML4521", 2000, 1500));


            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean modelFound = false;
            while (!modelFound) {
            System.out.print("Enter model to rent: ");
            String model = input.nextLine();

            for(Car s : carlist){
        if (model.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getModel())) {
         modelFound = true;
        System.out.println("Model  " + model + " is available");
        System.out.print("Enter number of days: ");
        int days = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("***************Details*****************");
        int cost = (days * s.getRate()) + s.getDeposit();
        System.out.println("Deposit  DailyRate  Duration  TotalCost");
        System.out.println(s.getDeposit() + "       " + s.getRate()+ "            " + days + "        " + cost);
        System.out.print("Proceed to rent?( y/n ): ");

        String dec = input.next();
       switch (dec) {
            case "y":
               System.out.println("Enter Customer Name: ");
                String name = input.next();
                System.out.println("Enter NIC Number: ");
                int num = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("************Receipt*************");
                System.out.println(     "     Date                               Name           NICNo         Car        RegNo    Duration   TCost");
          System.out.println(date+"           "+name + "          " + num +    "         " + model
                + "   " + s.getRegNo() + "      " + days + "       "+cost);
                break;
            case "n":
                System.out.println("Serving Next Customer: ");
                break;
                }
    }
        else{
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid model");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is not very well organized, so it's hard to tell what is where. Please add correct indentation so we can easily spot out loop and condition bodies.

Comment: then add a `loop` around your question block

Comment: You have written this program as though you were writing it in BASIC.  Embrace a more object-oriented paradigm.  By using objects, not only will your code be more readable, but your program will be far easier to maintain and extend.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a while loop:

```
boolean modelFound = false;
while (!modelFound) {
   // Ask question, take input
   String model = input.next();
   for (Object object : carList) {
   /* etc ... */
   if (model.equalsIgnoreCase(car.getModel()) {
       modelFound = true;
       /* other code */
   }
}
```

Also assuming your CarList uses a Car generic: `List<Car> carList`, then you don't need to cast every time, just run your for-each loop as `for (Car c : carList)`

Comment: @Rouge
Thankyou very much it worked but there seems to be another issue. When I put an else statement in the end which is 
    System.out.println("Please input a valid model");                        
it prints the above statement as many times as the number of values in array.

Comment: Can you update the OP with the code currently in use?

Comment: I have updated the program please take a look.

Comment: If you put it within the for loop and the model is wrong for every car, then it would say it for every car. Look at what you're comparing. (I'll reformat the code and look as well)

Comment: [Reformatted Code](http://pastie.org/8366971) - As you can see, you get the model, then compare it for every value in your car list. However, when the model types don't equal, then you print ("Please enter a valid model") for each car. Instead of writing an `else` within the for loop, I would recommend checking if modelFound is still false outside the for loop but inside the while loop. `if (!modelFound) { System.out.println("Enter valid model"); }`